# ionic mobile app gives white screen

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-cli

I have created one ionic app it runs perfectly fine in browser but when I convert it into app it gives white screen.

I have already install white list plugin and allowed all url in config and also have kept meta tag. Am not able to find any other solution.

When kept simple html file am able to view it.

Any help will be grateful.May be good way to debug will be also good.

Comment: I faced this issue too, are you using relative paths in your application?

Comment: @SatejS yes I used relative path it was loading good, thing was there was case sensitive name issue in one of plugin folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok just answering this question so it will be helpful to all.

Below blog was helpful for me that how I can debug
http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-debug-the-white-screen-of-death-in-your-ionic-app/

And guess what was issue, folder name in app is case sensitive. I was just need to change a folder name as per exact case sensitive path I provide in index file.

Answer (score 2):

Connect your phone to PC with USB cable and remember to keep USB Debugging On. Now, navigate to chrome://inspect. You'll find the device name and click on "inspect". On Console tab, the error list will give you a hint about what is wrong there. 
In my case, a custom service was Injected in controller which had been removed at some time as It was not used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly such thing occures because of a javascript error. You say it runs in your browser. Are there some exception in the console?

Not everythings is equal between browser and device, for example plugins. You have to be sure, that all used plugins are installed properly.

If you deploy on android, you can use android monitor to get console output. On ios xcode has already an integrated debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I had this horrible issue because I compiled my Android application with Cordova 6.x and the project worked with CrossWalk plugin. In my case, the solution was uninstalling Crosswalk. If your project has installed that plugin, try to uninstall it and compile your project again.