# ionic 2 blank after splash page under android 4.3

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

My question is similar to [ionic-mobile-app-gives-white-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643876/ionic-mobile-app-gives-white-screen)

I have created one ionic app that runs perfectly fine in a browser, but when I convert it into an app I am getting a white screen.

I have already installed the white list plugin and allowed all urls in the config. I also have kept the meta tag.

This is one ionic 2 application.

It runs perfectly in web and on all Android devices when I use ionic 1.

But, I can use Android 5.0 or higher version to run ionic2.

I have tried many methods such as [how-to-debug-the-white-screen-of-death-in-your-ionic-app](http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-debug-the-white-screen-of-death-in-your-ionic-app/), but i can't inspect button for my debug 
[chrome inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtZCv.jpg).

My android device: genymotion, htc one, running Android 4.3 (API 18).